# How do I inherit from Document object to my child object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to inherit from `Document` object in my code, but it is not working, Please how can I achieve this?

This is my code so far:

```
function Doc() {
    Document.call(this)
}

Doc.prototype = Object.create(Document.prototype);
Doc.prototype.constructor = Doc; 

var userdoc = new Doc();

// it is not working when I try to do
userdoc.querySelectorAll('[abs-text]')
```

Comment: First, what do you mean by "it is not working"? Second, why oh why would you ever need/want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Unlikely, though if at all you will need to use ES6 `class` syntax